# Qt Application Width increases when widgets visibility changes

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have developed a `Qt` application using `C++`. I have following widgets added to `QHLayout`:

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(sideBar_);
layout->addWidget(chromeTabs_, 1);
layout->addWidget(concPlot_, 1);
layout->addWidget(od_, 1);
layout->addWidget(settingWidget_);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
layout->setMargin(0);
layout->setSpacing(0);

setCentralWidget(widget);
```

Initially, `sideBar_` and `chromeTabs_` are visible. Then, a user can make `settingWidget_` visible by clicking on some button. When a user clicks on `OD button`, `chromeTabs_`  becomes invisible and `od_` becomes visible. However, my `Qt` application doesn't adjust itself and width of the application increases. I have to click on `Maximize` button to adjust it to the width of my laptop screen. I am unable to fix this issue. Can somebody help?

My code base is huge. So, I can't post my code over here.

Picture 1: After starting the application. :
[image]

Picture 2: After making settingWidget_ visible. Initially, `sideBar_` and `chromeTabs_` are visible. The application width adjusts automatically.
[image]

Picture 3: After making chromeTabs_ invisible and making od_ visible. You can see application width has increased.
[image]

Picture 4: After clicking on `Maximize` button. The application fits to the screen now.
[image]

Comment: Try setting the size policy of the container (object named `widget` in your case) to `fixed`: `widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy:Fixed)`

Comment: No, It didn't helped

Comment: Call update() method?

Comment: When you set sizePolicy to fixed, sizeHint is the only acceptable size. And the size hint returns invalid if widget is not in a  layout, otherwise the layout's preferred size(http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop). This means the layout that your widget belongs to is expandable. you may need to set the upper layers to be fixed to stop from being resized. Or simply you can get the screen resolution and set max size of your mainwindow.